# Converting String to Int in Android, JSON

Tags: android, string, int

Please give me an idea on how to compare values. I have a string budget_event, and budget and it is from my webserver. I think I should convert such strings into int and I need to compare those values with greater than and less than symbols. How can I implement these? Please give me some ideas. I'm new in these things.

Here's my code snippet in android. I need to convert the Budget and budget_event to int because they are strings. Any help will do. Thanks!

```
 Budget = jsonObject.getString("budget");
totalcost.setText(Budget);
budget_event = budget.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

Or, for floats:

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(yourString);
```

Comment: how can i compare the integers with <= or >=?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 int value = Integer.parseInt(Budget);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

If `Budge`t is not valid `int`, it throws a `NumberFormatException`.

```
  try {
       int value = Integer.parseInt(Budget);
  }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string value to `parseInt()` method of `Integer` class...you will get the converted value of the given string value.

```
int budget = Integer.parseInt(budget_event);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int budgetint = Integer.parseInt(budget);
if (budgetint <20)
...
```